# Is it possible to use a union type to restrict the "inherited" child types in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I am dealing with an underlying product that has something that could be expressed in GraphQL as the following "seed" schema:

```
interface Item {
   id: ID
   name: String
   content: [Item!]!
}

type Container implements Item {
   id: ID
   name: String
   content: [Item!]! # But really can only have Container(s) and Box(es)
}

type Box implements Item {
   id: ID
   name: String
   content: [Item!]! # But really can only have Box(es) and Thing(s)
}

type Thing implements Item {
   id: ID
   name: String
   #...
}
#...
```

I wanted to "focus" / "narrow" the `content` field of `Container` by creating `ContainerContent` and `BoxContent` as union types:

```
union ContainerContent = Container | Box

union BoxContent = Box | Thing
```

... so that I could do:

```
type Container implements Item {
   id: ID
   name: String
   content: [ContainerContent!]!
}

type Box implements Item {
   id: ID
   name: String
   content: [BoxContent!]!
}
```

Each possible type in the union is an `Item` so I expected this to be fine... but the framework I am using (`graphql-java`) is failing to to validate this and complains that the:

```
object type 'Container' does not implement interface 'Item' because field 'content' is defined as '[ContainerContent!]!' type and not as '[Item!]!' type
```

I do not wish to take the `content` property out of the base (interface) `Item` if I don't have to. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Well... it turns out it just isn't possible - at least not yet.